# Removing empty white bar in HTML

Tags: html, css, electron, css-position

I'm just coding an "exit" button for a game client I'm making in electron, and after writing the code for the button it shows up with a huge white bar beside it. I was also wondering how to move it up and into the top middle of the page with translateX(percentage) and couldn't figure it out. =

[image: White bar bug]

```css
.ExitButton {
  color: red;
  font-size: 25px;
  max-width: 55px;
  length: 30px;
  border-color: black;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

.ExitButton:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

.Exitbutton {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<webview src="https://bapbap.gg"></webview>

<button class="ExitButton" onclick="alert('Are you sure you want to exit BapClient?')">Exit</button>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that this occurs because your body tag has white background-color, try changing it with the background color of the page, or you can also do something like this:

```css
.ExitButton {
/* ... */
position: absolute;
/* make the button 0 pixels away from bottom of the page */
bottom:0;
/* you can use top, left or right just like this way 
to put the button on anywhere on the page you want */
}
```

This would essentially give an absolute position to your button and enable you to put it anywhere you want. Use `z-index` if it overlaps with some elements.